# how to exclude files with certain prefix in azure data factory pipeline while copying the data

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-adf

I want to exclude the .mp4 file while copying it from Azure Storage (blob) to Sftp. Following is my source settings

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use GetMetadata activity to get the list of all files in folder and then filter out that array for .mp4 file.
Use this filtered out output as input for for each activity and iterate over each file

Comment: can't we directly do using wildcard path or prefix by using expressions and functions?

Comment: I am looking for the most optimized solution. Do you know if we can use multiple patterns/prefixes in a wildcard file name?